# Trying to stop removing `div` if it's length at `0` or `1`. can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to stop removing `div` if it's length at `0` or `1`. can someone help me?

Here is link: https://jsfiddle.net/Issact/ncqnv8zs/

HTML & JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.div').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    var divLength = $('.main div').length;
    $('.mainLength').text(divLength + " " + 'divs');

    if (divLength === 1) {
      $(this).stop().remove();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="div">Div one</div>
  <div class="div">Div Two</div>
  <div class="div">Div Three</div>
  <div class="div">Div Four</div>
</div>

<div class="mainLength">
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you remove your div only if the length is different than 1 rather than canceling the deletion.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this in your fiddle and i believe that this is the behavior you want to achieve.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.div').click(function() {

    var divLength = $('.main div').length;
    $('.mainLength').text(divLength + " " + 'divs');

    if (divLength > 1) {
      $(this).remove();
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must check your condition before removing divs and if length not 1, remove it and decrease `divLength` variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.div').click(function() {
    var divLength = $('.main div').length;

    if (divLength !== 1) {
      $(this).remove();
      divLength--;
    }
    $('.mainLength').text(divLength + " " + 'divs');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="div">Div one</div>
  <div class="div">Div Two</div>
  <div class="div">Div Three</div>
  <div class="div">Div Four</div>
</div>

<div class="mainLength">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't actually need `divLength--` because the `divLength` is set to the correct number every time a `div` is clicked.

Comment: Are you tried it?! If click on div and remove a div, length decreasing by one div! @vi5ion

Comment: On every click this line is executed `var divLength = $('.main div').length;`. This will get the number of divs that are present at that time, so the ones that you removed on previous clicks are no longer found by this selector.

Comment: Ah wait sorry, now I see why you did it. This line is still below it in your code `$('.mainLength').text(divLength + " " + 'divs');` but you could move that line up before the if statement.

Comment: Yes, for previous removing is OK. but for current remove, it must be decrease by one.

Comment: `$('.mainLength').text(divLength + " " + 'divs');` depends on delete, if doesn't delete not change for `divLength` and if deleted, must be decrease.

Comment: Yes you're right, I said that in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
        var divLength = $('.main div').length;
          $('.mainLength').text(divLength + " " + 'divs');

          if(divLength > 1){
            $(this).remove();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplify your code as much as possible, check out bellow:

```js
$('.div').click(function(){
  if($('.main .div').length > 1)
    $(this).remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="div">Div one</div>
  <div class="div">Div Two</div>
  <div class="div">Div Three</div>
  <div class="div">Div Four</div>
</div>

<div class="mainLength">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check div length before removing a div element.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.div').click(function () {

                var divLength = $('.main div').length;
                if (divLength > 1) {
                    $(this).remove();
                    $('.mainLength').text(divLength - 1 + " " + 'divs');
                    //$(this).stop().remove();
                }

            });
        });
```